# How to add edges with a list as label in Networkx Python

Tags: python, list, graph, networkx

I have this example:

```
G.add_nodes_from(List1)
G.add_nodes_from(List2)
edgeList = list(zip(List1, List2))
for item in List3:
    G.add_edges_from(edgeList, label = item)
```

What I want as outcome is each edge between the two lists to have as a label the corresponding  element of the list3. Something like this:

(List1[0], List2[0], {'label': List3[0]})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: I have change the variable name from `List1` to `source_nodes`, `List2` to `dest_nodes` and `List3` to `data_nodes` in the following code.

You can try to use `zip` over all three lists and add the edges using [nx.add_edge](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html). Something like this:

```
import networkx as nx

source_nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
dest_nodes = ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S']
data_nodes = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

G = nx.DiGraph()

# Each element of this zip will be
# (source[i], dest[i], data[i]) 
for u,v,d in zip(source_nodes, dest_nodes, data_nodes):
    G.add_edge(u, v, label=d)

print(G.edges(data=True))
# OutEdgeDataView([('A', 'P', {'label': 'W'}),
#                  ('B', 'Q', {'label': 'X'}),
#                  ('C', 'R', {'label': 'Y'}),
#                  ('D', 'S', {'label': 'Z'})])
```

You can also view the code in [this Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eidi3zoj1b1tAyR00tYxGq1NyJseW3LH) for more info.